# How to integrate spiderfier js with gmaps4rails gem ? (Multiple markers on same lat,lng )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I'm struggling a bit trying to integrate spiderfier https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier with https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

In my map.html.haml:

```
= gmaps(:markers => {:data => @map, :options => { "rich_marker" => true, :raw => '{ animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }' } }, :map_options => { :draggable => true, :auto_zoom => false, :zoom => 9, :disableDefaultUI => false, :scrollwheel => true, :disableDoubleClickZoom => true, :custom_infowindow_class => "province" })

- content_for :scripts do
:javascript
    Gmaps.map.infobox = function(boxText) {
        return {
             content: boxText
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -50)
            ,alignBottom: true
            ,zIndex: 999
            ,hideCloseButton: false
            ,boxStyle: { 
                background: "white"
                ,width: "280px"
                ,padding: "10px"
                ,border: "1px solid #b2b2b2"
                ,arrowStyle: 0
                ,arrowPosition: 50
                ,arrowSize: 20
                 }

            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(10, 10)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false

     }};
```

This works fine, but how would one integrate spiderfier https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier#how-to-use ?

Comment: I came across the same problem today. Did you find a solution in the meantime? Thanks

Comment: Hi Patrick, I haven't found a solution yet, will comment here if I do but the priority is fortunately not that high for the client.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question using an old version of Gmaps 4 Rails, however to anyone that is interested in working with both libs in their latest versions, here's how to do it.

This example is based off the [documentation sample code](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails#requirements)

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
      "picture": {
        "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
        "width":  36,
        "height": 36
      },
      "infowindow": "hello!"
    }
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();

  // Create a OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier instance
  var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(handler.getMap(), {
    keepSpiderfied: true
    // Other options you need
  });

  // Track each marker with OMS
  _.each(markers, function(marker) {
    oms.addMarker(marker.getServiceObject());
  });
});
```

The important thing here is to get down to the native Google objects that Gmaps4Rails wraps inside its own classes.

If you need click events on your markers, add a single handler to `oms` as it is explained [in the doc](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier#how-to-use).

Comment: Also, load the google maps API before OMS if your client cannot reference OMS. An easy way to do this is to add the OMS `js` file inline instead of as a header.